# Insert multiple entries in parameterized query

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to do a multiple insert query using a parameterized command but I am getting a syntax exception thrown. The query in sql would look like:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEMP_PTO ( 
    ng_id INT, 
    requested_hours DECIMAL(7,4)
);

INSERT INTO TEMP_PTO VALUES
(1, 0.0000), (2, 1.5000);
```

I generate it in C# via the following where `ptoHours` is an `IEnumerable` of a class containing the `ng_id` and the `requested_hours`. `Queries` is an `resx` file containing the query text, and `Queries.PTOLoadTempCommand` = `INSERT INTO TEMP_PTO VALUES @v;`:

```
        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(this.connString))
        {
            MySqlTransaction trans = null;
            try
            {
                await conn.OpenAsync();
                trans = conn.BeginTransaction();

                using (var tempCommand = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    tempCommand.CommandText = Queries.PTOTempTableCommand;
                    await tempCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                }

                using (var loadCommand = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    loadCommand.CommandText = Queries.PTOLoadTempCommand; //INSERT INTO TEMP_PTO VALUES @v;
                    loadCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v", String.Join(", " ,ptoHours.Select(p => String.Format("({0}, {1:N4})", p.AgentId, p.UsedVacationHours))));
                    //Exception thrown here
                    var affected = await loadCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    if (affected != entryCount)
                        throw new Exception("Not All Entries Loaded");
                }

                trans.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if(trans!= null) trans.Rollback();
            }
        }
```

Looking at the `loadCommand` object, I can see that the value of the parameter `@v` is `(1, 0.0000), (2, 1.5000)`. Are you able to do an insert like this or do I need to modify the function to insert them one at a time? I know I could go the `StringBuilder` route, but then I cannot use the safety of the parameterization.

Comment: You can use StringBuilder and parameterized queries together, you just have to make sure you "build" as many parameters as you will need. That said, in my experience the time needed to execute prepared parameterized queries in a loop does not differ much from the time required to execute multi-value inserts. (With a large amount of data, there can be an optimal mix of the two, like preparing a parameterized statement that inserts 10 rows at a time for example, but it is highly situationally dependent.)

Comment: Do you need it to insert only 2 values at a time? If it is the case, @Sami is right, you can do 2 inserts in the transaction and it is fine. If later you need to insert thousands of rows, you'd better go to something else like MySqlBulkLoader

Comment: @sroll I only put 2 as an example. It will load on average between 1,300 - 2k entries. Can you bulk load into a temp table?

Comment: @JRLambert You can for sure with SqlServer and Oracle, but sorry I have no idea with MySql. with 1000-2000 entries I think it is probably better to start thinking about bulk insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do it one at a time. The query parameters are parsed and it is not allowed to have a parameter in that position.

There shouldn't be a need to insert rows in one command, if you need both to succeed or fail, just use transactions.

And as you said, using a StringBuilder or other string catenations is not smart.